# How do I run the source code of Google Ads?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, google-ads-api

I want to run the Google Ads app on Visual Studio Code. This is the github: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter

I thought that if it is written in flutter, I could run it with "flutter run", but that doesn't work. It says that needs to know the location of main.dart file.

Comment: This is a plugin. You don't run it alone, just as you don't run a library. You use it. Open a flutter project, add this plugin, and try use its features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link is just for the plulgin of flutter. What you might run is the example folder of it. here's the [link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/tree/main/packages/google_mobile_ads/example). And then run `flutter pub get` after running that.